# fast uploads of file when using node.js

Tags: android, html, node.js, file-upload

I am new to the concept of Node.js. Basically, I am looking to upload files from an Android client to a server (that will holds files).

I saw this post:
http://www.hacksparrow.com/handle-file-uploads-in-express-node-js.html

but - my concern is what would happen if there was no connection to upload a picture (ex: if someone was "out of range" - or - the place where one currently is has a slow connection)? Is there some kind of way that the command can be "buffered" and then, once a good connection is encountered (from maybe the wifi at a library or a school), the upload(s) take place? Perhaps someone can use something like ActiveMQ? I think Google Drive handles this but - it takes a *long* time to upload a number of files. The files would be about 4MB - 30MB in size.

Is there a way to get around such a problem? Can HTML be used - or - would some kind of hybrid (of HTML/Android app) have to be created.

TIA

Answer (score 2):

This is my opinion and it may not be the best way to handle this situation
I think

- Step 1)it's better to  convert your file into base64 string first
- Step 2) split the string into for example 100 parts
- Step 3) save each part in sqlite database (fileID, partID, base64Str,
  isUploaded)
- Step 4) upload each part to server (a database on your server) and
  Mark each uploaded part as isUploaded=1 in sqlite database.
- Step 5) reconstruct file and decide it to original format.
- Step 6) clear sqlite database.